# alternative method to getVisibleTitleHeight() to make it run on Android sdk 4.3

Tags: android, android-webview

Is there any alternative method for getVisibleTitleHeight(). This Webview method is removed android 4.3 onwards. Here is my code snippet.

---

// here the canvas for a picture bitmap is created

Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);

Webview view = new Webview();
 int yScaleFactor = view.getVisibleTitleHeight();

float overviewScale = (scaledWidth)/
                       (webView.getScale() * width);

canvas.translate(0,yScaleFactor*overviewScale);

I tried to obtain similar o/p to view.getVisibleTitleHeight() using other method, but couldnt get an exactly similar o/p . Please guide .

Answer (score 0):

It is still there, it is annotated with `@hide`, so you cannot use it in your code. May be you can compile you code using : http://devmaze.wordpress.com/2011/01/18/using-com-android-internal-part-1-introduction/

However, this method will always return 0 according to the comment in  `WebViewChromium.getVisibleTitleHeight()` method:

> This is deprecated in WebView and should always return 0.